# Pc overheats doing Basic Tasks

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cooling, overheating

I have a Dell Precision 7510 running Windows 10, in January my computer began having overheating problems doing basic tasks like firing up an internet browser, initially this seemed really strange since never before had my laptop shut down after just doing basic tasks. I recently cleaned up the dust vents and 3 moths ago cleaned and changed the thermal compound. Since then I have used the machine for rendering and playing videogames so it wasn't really a hardware issue. To make sure, I ran the DELL Diagnostics tool that all DELL motherboards have, and ran a CPU stress test, conveniently temperatures never reached 60° C.

For a few days since I mostly do coding, I ignored the problem and just did not played videogames, I made sure to have a HWinfo window open just to monitor the temperature and never really ran into issues (avg temperatures ranged 40 - 60° C). However one day it got to the point that just booting up made the  computer shutdown immediately, what I tried to do was lift my laptop and make the air inlets face an AC unit to at least boot and enter safe-mode. In safe-mode I retrieved all my personal data and program configurations, formatted the disk,  and reinstalled Windows 10 21H2. It initially worked but eventually I opened up my internet browser and it happened once again, upon opening, the CPU reaches 80% usage and shuts down. It seems to me that windows just doesn't use the CPU efficiently. Does anybody have a suggestion or things that I could try?

I have installed Opera, python libraries, VIM and office. There's nothing else on this computer.

Comment: What model is your computer? Why do you think its overheating? (it is very unlikely its shutting down from overheating - computers slow down (throttlle) they don't shut down for heating. It might be your psu is dodgy and/or a bbattery issue.

Comment: You have monitored temperature before, why all of the sudden didn't you check temperature while this problem is occuring and if so, why haven't you posted what the temps are in this problem?

Comment: When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Comment: It's a laptop. These overheat and shutdown when the cooling vanes become clogged with dust. This happens regularly when no stripping and cleaning is ever performed.

Comment: Considering simple booting already causes overheating, I'm wondering if somehow the thermal paste on the CPU dried out.
Not exactly a basic task though, so if this is your first time cleaning the heatsink and applying new paste you might want to read up a bit first.

Comment: OP already cleaned and applied new thermal paste. // Are you sure the heat sink is mounted properly? What temperature is 60 degrees? There are many sensors around the device and even inside the CPU or GPU. Did you check all of them? // I also agree with davidgo. Thermal shutdown would indicate very critical temperature levels.

Comment: It could be that the heatsink wasn't quite on the CPU properly so it seemed to tighten down OK but has since moved. It is also not impossible that it was tightened down too much and a fastener has broken free. Either way, inspection of the heatsink seems to be in order.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It has been 3 months since I changed the thermal paste, so I don't really think that may be a problem

Comment: @MiG As stated, I ran Dell's Diagnostics CPU stress test, it is in my understanding that it puts considerable heavier loads than any processing required to open up Opera.

Comment: @davidgo Laptop fans ramp up to maximum before shutting down.

Comment: @james do you have evidence for your assertion about laptop fans ramping up to maximum before shutting down? Why would they shut down after ramping up to maximum?

Comment: @davidgo I think you got me wrong. The laptop ramps up it's fans to maximum, before the laptop itself shuts down, not it's fans, since the laptop shuts down, I am unable to open up HWinfo to take a screenshot of Fan RPMs.

Comment: The E3 v5 family of processors that the 7510 comes with Intels "Thermal Monitoring Technologies"  (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/93354/intel-xeon-processor-e31575m-v5-8m-cache-3-00-ghz.html) - that CPU should not be able to overheat (ie it should slow down if it gets too hot).  Something is very wrong - but unless the CPU is damaged this is not a CPU cooling issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on a Dell Precision 7510 with AMD graphics card, found that the thermal paste had dried out, so I cleaned and applied new thermal paste. There was a slight improvement, but the problem was not solved. I then searched and found a YouTube video series which seems to show that the copper cooling "pipe(s)" on the CPU/Graphics card heatsink fan assembly can fail:

[Dell Precision 7510 overheating heatsink diagnostics
(Part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5HlScq8qD0)

[Dell Precision 7510 overheating heatsink diagnostics
(Part 2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8oalV_Qd9Y)

[Dell Precision 7510 overheating heatsink diagnostics
(Part 3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pspzNy2m7w)

I will be replacing the heatsink fan assembly to see if it solves the problem. Note that there are different heatsink fan assembly parts for the Dell Precision 7510, depending on the type of discrete graphics card in the laptop:

For laptop with Nvidia graphics card, the Dell part # I found is 44PG6

For laptop with AMD graphics card, the Dell part # I found is DGTVT

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1125299)